# think + object + to infinitive

Tags: grammaticality

Can I write 'think + object + to infinitive'?

"He is thought to have stolen the money."

Is this sentence correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct; the instances of use of this construction abound ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20thought%20to%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)).

This use of the verb is according to its plain meaning "have opinion/belief"  ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/think_1?q=think))).

> **be thought to be somebody/something**
>
> - He's thought to be one of the richest men in Europe.

Your sentence means that there are people thinking that he is the one to have stollen the money.

The verb pattern for this usage in a paper version of OALD is [VN+to inf]; however, a little note at the entry for this construction tells the reader that [the] "pattern is not usually used unless **think** is in the passive". Therefore, the title of your sentence is correct on the grounds of mere structure but not of usage, as in normal usage there is no more object (the object becomes the subject in the passive turn). The "usage construction" is therefore as follows.

- Sbjt + be thought + to infinitive

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your sentence, but it lacks an object. *He* is subject in the passive construction given.

With an object in the active voice it would read something like:

*They thought **him** to have stolen the money*

And it would still be good English.

Comment: Goodish. Grammatical, but rarefied. And imagine 'They thought the notorious gang of outlaws that had been terrorising the surrounding towns and villages for months to have stolen the money.' I'd stick with the passive form.